# Protractor: how to store the text value of a component and re-use it in a spec?

Tags: protractor

I have a string displayed in a page and I want to store this string in a variable so I can use this variable for a check further in the test process.

Here is what it looks like:

```
    let storedValue: string;
    element(by.id('myElement')).getText().then((elementValue: string) => {
      storedValue = elementValue;
      console.log('stored value: ' + storedValue);
    });

    // Some unrelated code will go here in the future

    browser.wait(() => storedValue !== null, 5000, 'browser.wait timeout');
    expect(element(by.id('myElement')).getText()).toEqual(storedValue);
```

If the string in the page is *hello*, the test fails with the log `Expected 'Hello' to equal undefined.`

Why is it still undefined ?

I thought that Protractor would queue the last two instructions synchronously in the ControlFlow.

Maybe there is another way to store this variable, or to wait for the `storedValue` to be defined ?

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.wait(() => storedValue !== null, 5000, 'browser.wait timeout').then(function(){
    expect(element(by.id('myElement')).getText()).toEqual(storedValue);
});
```

Setting up the expect inside the wait will solve your problem. However, I don't know enough about the specifics of ControlFlow to explain exactly why yours doesn't work. Hopefully someone else can come along and do that.

Comment: Indeed your solution works. Now I'm not totally reassured because between the storing (the first `by.id`) and the verification (the second `by.id`), the test goes on another page that also include a component `myElement`. Are we sure that, at verification, the first promise still reads the component on the first page an not the component on the second page ?

Comment: @Coli The `browser.wait()` is purely waiting for `storedValue !-- null`. The component text is stored in the variable and at this point is no longer related to the page element so changing pages should not affect `storedValue`.

Comment: Thanks for the precision. Still my main issue is not fixed: following Protractor's doc, `browser.wait()` and `expect()` should run synchronously. For the sake of clarity in my test code, the `storedValue` should be usable outside of a callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can force expect to run inside control flow by doing a browser.call

```
browser.call(() => expect(element(by.id('myElement')).getText()).toEqual(storedValue));
```

But you shouldn't have to do this. Could be a bug.